# Recurly data to grafana

Tags: grafana, recurly

We are looking for any open source tool to get the analytics data from Recurly to grafana. Is there any such tool please suggest us.

Regards,
Sreenath

Comment: Are you referring to loading the data export data from recurly into Grafana? Or where are you getting your events / datastream from?

Answer (score 0):

At this time, there is not a way to export the data feeding Recurly Analytics directly. Many merchants consume webhooks (https://docs.recurly.com/docs/webhooks) and/or Automated Exports (https://docs.recurly.com/docs#section-automated-exports)  in order to build their own external analytics.